# Project Reactor back pressure doesn't work when producer and consumer working in different threads

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a problem that I can't achive working backpressure for my code

```
        Flux<Entity> entityStream = parseService.parseEntites(resource);
        entityStream
                .buffer(bufferSize)
                .takeWhile(indicatorBatch -> onTakeWhile())
                .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .doOnError(ignored -> cancelTransaction(resource.getId()))
                .subscribe(entityBatch -> onDownloadBatch(entityBatch),
                        error -> onDownloadError(error),
                        () -> onDownloadComplete())
```

parseService.parseEntites(resource) looks like:

```
    public Flux<Indicator> parseEntites(ResourceEntity resource) {
        return Flux.create(emitter -> {
            try {
                Parser parser = getParser(resource);
                parser.parseResource(resource);
                emitter.complete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                emitter.error(e);
            }
        });
    }
```

where parser can be rest client or file parser and so on that fetching data in blocking manere and call emmiter.next(entity) on each parsed entity

onDownloadBatch() performs saving entites to db in blocking manere

The main idea is to perform downloading and saving into db in parralell with backpressure. Consumer and producer works in separate threads and if saving to db slower than downloading, producer should pause producing untill consumer consumes buffer.
I tried to use .limitRate() for entityStream and also tried to use my custom Subscriber with overided methods instead of lambdas in subscribe() section

```
        @Override
        protected void hookOnSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
            request(1);
        }

        @Override
        protected void hookOnNext(List<Entity> batch) {
            onDownloadBatch(batch);
            request(1);
        }

        @Override
        protected void hookOnError(Throwable throwable) {
            onDownloadError(resource, transactionId, throwable);
        }
```

But it doesn't help, producer produces entites with it's own rate. Is it any way to achive described result? It will be grate to have an ability to control how much batches can be in buffer before pause producing